# Spock Metaprogramming getProperty()

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, spock

I'd like to override the `getProperty()` method in a Spock test, per the documentation of [get/setProperty](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/core-metaprogramming.html#_get_setproperty). This is trivial in a normal Groovy class, but doesn't seem to work inside a Spock specification.

```
class MainSpec extends Specification {
    @Override
    def getProperty(String name) {
        def value = metaClass.getProperty(this, name)
        println "$name == $value"
        return value
    }

    String foo = 'foo'

    def test() {
        expect:
        foo
        println foo
    }
}
```

This example does not invoke the `getProperty()` method. It appears Spock is bypassing it somehow. Is there a way to hook into Spock's property resolution mechanism, or tell Spock to use my overridden method?

Comment: May I inquire what is the use-case for this?

Comment: I have an integration spec with a large number of properties that essentially represent identifiers in external systems. The data these IDs map to is volatile, but I can validate all the properties ahead of time and short-circuit the more expensive tests by intercepting their `getProperty()` invocations. At minimum, this gives me a consistent failure message for tests that have bad data.

Comment: Spock uses AST transformations and compiles the spec, without looking in further my guess it that it does not use groovy MOP for locally defined properties. Why don't you use a property holder class that you can use normal meta programming, it would also better separate your logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that moving the property to a parent class is sufficient to make it pass through the `getProperty()` interceptor, even when the parent is another `Specification` class.

```
class BaseSpec extends Specification {
    def foo = 'foo'
}

class MainSpec extends BaseSpec {
    @Override
    def getProperty(String name) {
        def value = super.getProperty(name)
        println "$name == $value"
        return value
    }

    def test() {
        expect:
        foo
        println foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use "Expando" style, where the property should not be defined on the Spec class but is stored in a map (`storage`) and manipulated by `setProperty` and `getProperty` methods:

```
class MetaprogrammingSpec extends Specification {
    def storage = [:]

    @Override
    def getProperty(String name) {
        def value = storage[name]
        println "$name == $value"
        return value
    }

    @Override
    void setProperty(String name, value) {
        storage[name] = value
    }

    def test() {
        when:
        foo = 'bar'

        then:
        foo
        println foo
    }
}
```

Then the result is:
[image]

**Update after comment:** The `getProperty()` method is also called when you don't initialize the `foo` property. When you change the test in this way:

```
def test() {
    expect:
    foo
    println foo
}
```

The result is as expected - `getProperty()` was called but test failes because `foo` is `null`:
[image]

Comment: It seems this only works because `foo` is an unresolved symbol. Add `def` in front of its assignment and `getProperty()` is no longer invoked.

Comment: If you add def, foo is local to the method, so isn't a property

Comment: As @tim_yates said if you add `def` then it will be local to the method and `getProperty()` cannot be called. See the answer update - `getProperty()` is also called when you remove the `when` section with `foo` value assignent.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the local variable change was obvious; but I'm still struggling to understand why the property cannot be declared in the spec.